# pip is not correctly installing many packages (no error messages)

Tags: installation, python, pip

I have tried installing several packages with pip. The command will finish running without error but the package won't show up (e.g., when I type '''which x'''). When I uninstall the package, it does so successfully, so I know it is there somewhere!

Using Python 2.7.1.6 and pip 19.2.3

Comment: Does `which X` even show Python packages generally? Wouldn't that be solely for modules that had separate command line interfaces (e.g. `pylint` or `gtts`)? Why don't you just `import X` in the standard Python REPL? Or [pip show X](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/)?

Comment: Yes, the main thing I'm trying to install has a separate command line interface (it's called psiturk). When that wasn't working to install, I tried with a few other packages to see if it was a problem with pip and I noticed that other packages also didn't work, suggesting it's not a problem with the specific package (psiturk) but a general one.